# Looping through dictionary to update Hosted Features in a Pro doc

Tags: python, layers, for-loop

I am trying to update a dictionary of hosted feature layers, the key is the layer name, and the value is the SDE path of the layer where the updated data will be truncated and appended with. For loops leave me very confused, and I can't find any other documentation of how to update hosted layers in Pro, I believe originally I was calling the List Layers like a string and tried to correct it but am still getting the following error, aprx_sde is my dictionary.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'listLayers'

```
layer_names = i.name [l.name for l in map.listLayers()]
    for i.name in map.listLayers():
    path_sde    = aprx_sde[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of layer_names and indentation are both wrong.  Something like this should work for you.

```py
# Define project and map
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps("Map")[0]

# Loop through layer names
for lyr in [l.name for l in m.listLayers()]:

    # If the layer name is in your dictionary
    if lyr in aprx_sde.keys():

        # Do whatever you want with the layer and aprx_sde[lyr]
```

Comment: When trying this I get the following error, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'listMaps'

Comment: You need to update "Map" with the name of the map your data layers are in, that is just the placeholder default name. Alternatively, I think you can use p.activeMap.